# Anyone managed to do cross remote debug in zend studio?

Tags: php, remote-debugging, zend-studio

I have two projects **A** and **B** .

My debug starts by accessing a url of **A**,and breakpoint works.And **A** need to curl **B**,how can I make it stop there?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how the debugger would follow a curl request across to another site (even if on the same server). In my experience, the debugging session ends when the request that started it returns. So, as another example, if the code redirects to another url on the same site, the debugger stops at the redirect; it doesn't pick up the redirected request.

Given that, I'm thinking you need to capture whatever curl's submitting to B, and submit the same request from your browser. Then you should be able to debug the interaction with B. But basically debugging is about a relationship between your local machine and a specific request to a server. So you can debug a request to A, or a request to B, but only one at a time.